# Promise.all() resolves to give the same value for each promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am writing a module which has a function to return a promise using `Promise.all()` to send emails to several users. Stripping down the code, I was able to reproduce the problem to the following snippet:

```
var getPromise = function(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("After Calling:\t\t", data.user);
        setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("While Resolving:\t", data.user);
                return resolve(data);
            },
            Math.random() * 1000);
    });
}

var getAllPromises = function(users, options) {
    var promises = [];
    users.forEach(user => {
        var userSpecificOptions = options;
        // var userSpecificOptions = {};
        userSpecificOptions.user = user;
        promises.push(getPromise(userSpecificOptions));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

var userlist = ["help", "promises", "are", "tough"];
var commonoptions = {
    str: "something",
}

getAllPromises(userlist, commonoptions)
    .then(data => console.log("Data:\n", data))
```

This gives me the following output:

```
After Calling:       help
After Calling:       promises
After Calling:       are
After Calling:       tough
While Resolving:     tough
While Resolving:     tough
While Resolving:     tough
While Resolving:     tough
Data:
 [ { str: 'something', user: 'tough' },
  { str: 'something', user: 'tough' },
  { str: 'something', user: 'tough' },
  { str: 'something', user: 'tough' } ]
```

However, switching the declaration for `userSpecificOptions`:

```
        // var userSpecificOptions = options;
        var userSpecificOptions = {};
```

gets the correct result:

```
After Calling:       help
After Calling:       promises
After Calling:       are
After Calling:       tough
While Resolving:     help
While Resolving:     promises
While Resolving:     are
While Resolving:     tough
Data:
 [ { user: 'help' },
  { user: 'promises' },
  { user: 'are' },
  { user: 'tough' } ]
```

What could be the issue? I feel there might be something that I'm missing about how Promises work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make all `userSpecificOptions` instances refer to the same `options` object:

```
var userSpecificOptions = options;
```

So, when you assign to `userSpecificOptions.user`, you actually modify `options`.

Instead, you should take a copy of `options`:

```
var userSpecificOptions = Object.assign({}, options);
```

Or using the object literal spread:

```
var userSpecificOptions = {...options};
```

Then any change to that particular `userSpecificOptions` object, will not affect `options` or any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not in promises. In Javascript objects is pass by reference. It means that in this case you always change the same object and the last change takes place and you see all the same results. And it works right when create new object instead of modifying existence one.